# Zend framework - how can i update the row if status field and id match?

Tags: php, zend-framework

How to updates the status='ok' only when status is NULL or done or notdone and id matches?

```
  $this->db->update('table1', 
                        array('status' => 'ok'), 
                        array('id=?' => 55));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your comparison you can't use an array for the where part of the statement. Instead you should use the `Where` class.

Add at the top of the .php file the following:

```
    use Zend\Db\Sql\Where;
```

Then where you use now the array you should use the `Where` instance:

```
    $where = new Where();
    $where->equalTo('id', 55);
    $where->expression("( status IN('done','notdone') OR status IS NULL )", array() );
    $this->db->update('table1', 
                    array('status' => 'ok'), 
                    $where );
```